# Ejabbered Offline message API requests

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I'm currently looking to get an existing ejabbered 17.09 instance to call against an API when offline messages are received.

I found a number of modules online, the best of which appeared to be the mod_offline_post from https://github.com/adamvduke/mod_interact

When I couldn't progress with this, I tried to follow the guide at 
https://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages/  but hit the same erlang compile issues:

```
12> c(mod_offline_post).
mod_offline_post.erl: undefined parse transform 'lager_transform'
error
```

My user folder looks like this

[image]

Not sure on the best way to proceed: to fix the compile error, or if there's a different module I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that mod_offline_post was last updated five years ago, so I doubt it will work with recent ejabberd versions, even if it compiles.

Regarding that compilation error, you will get it with any module that uses logging (with lines like ?INFO_MSG and ?DEBUG...), because your compilation system lacks some stuff. You can try to remove those lines in the source code, so at least it compiles.

Comment: Removing the dependency on logger.hrl exposed other dependencies I was able to fill, and a .beam file produced. Thanks!